# How do I sum only positive numbers from another column that must match certain criteria in my first column?

Tags: excel

I have about 500 item #s in Column A that represent all of the different items we put in or out of production during the week.

In Column F I have the total lbs of that item with positive or negative numbers reflecting in to production and out of production respectively.

I already have the following formula setup to tell me what the total loss/gain is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"0883","0884","0885"},A6:A280)))*F6:F280)
```

I would like to then sum only the positive numbers so that I can get a shrink/gain percentage based on the product we put into the room. This is where I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the SUMIF() function of Excel.
Here's a link to [Office.com](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumif-HP005209292.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can add another condition as follows:

=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"0883","0884","0885"},A6:A280))) * F6:F280 * (F6:F280>0))

Answer (score 0):

You can just extend your formula with another condition like this

`=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"0883","0884","0885"},A6:A280))*(F6:F280>0),F6:F280)`

What sort of values are in A6:A280? Which version of Excel are you using? - if `0883` etc. will be the full cell contents then you don't really need SEARCH and you might be able to use SUMIFS which will be more efficient, i.e. this version given your comments

`=SUM(SUMIFS(F6:F280,A6:A280,{"0883","0884","0885"},F6:F280,">0"))`

Comment: Column A is a 4 digit item number in text format since there is a leading zero for some of the items. I am using 2010. I tried sumifs but it would never add in the second value. It would only return a 0.

Comment: You need to wrap the SUMIFS in a SUM function so that it counts all 3 items, see my edited answer